# ${\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} - \sqrt{x^2+3})^{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$${\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}}(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} - \sqrt{x^2+3})^{x}$$

I tried taking log both sides (on paper). 
After taking log how do I proceed? You get $\infty$ * $(\infty-\infty$). But $\infty-\infty$ could be any number. How can I take this as 0? Even if I take it as zero, the question becomes nasty.

Please help me solve this limit. It must be solved without using series expansion as this isn't taught. Only L'Hopital and basic algebra.

Comment: Rationalise what's inside the bracket, it should then give you a $1^\infty$ form

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B3%29-sqrt%28x%5E2%2B3%29%29%5Ex) says that the limit is $1/\sqrt{e}$, if that's any help.

Comment: Yea that matches with the answer key :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} - \sqrt{x^2+3}\right)^{x}$$ For what is inside the parenthesis, use Taylor
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}=x+1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+3}=x+\frac{3}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x+3} - \sqrt{x^2+3}=1-\frac{1}{2 x}-\frac{1}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

$$\log(A)=x \log\left(1-\frac{1}{2 x}-\frac{1}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \right)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{8 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}-\frac{9}{8 \sqrt{e} x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Answer (score 0):

When you rationalise the inside you get

$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{x^2}}}\right)^x$$

This is a $1^\infty$ form, hence we can rewrite as

$$L = \exp{\left(\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{x^2}}}\right)-x\right)}$$